# how to hide/show element according to url parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have 4 url parameters like so

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/post?&id=5f04698e6114e4069099d8bf#like
http://127.0.0.1:4000/post?&id=5f04698e6114e4069099d8bf#comment
http://127.0.0.1:4000/post?&id=5f04698e6114e4069099d8bf#share
http://127.0.0.1:4000/post?&id=5f04698e6114e4069099d8bf#save
```

and 4 divs like
**html**

```
<div id='like' class='hide'></div>
<div id='comment' class='hide'></div>
<div id='share' class='hide'></div>
<div id='save' class='hide'></div>
```

and
**css**

```
.hide{
    display:none;
    }
```

how do i unhide elements when a url param is searched,
for example if i search for

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/post?&id=5f04698e6114e4069099d8bf#like
```

the div with `id='like` should be now visible

> what i have tried
> i have tried to unhide the elements on button click, and I am successful using `classList.toggle('hide')`
> but how do I achieve the same thing with changes in url. I would be best if the `classList` is set acc to the url for example when there is `#like` in url ,the element with id like should not contain the class `hide` anymore. other answers are also accepted ,thanks.

Comment: Add your `Html` please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No JavaScript needed. Use the CSS [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector like:

```
#like.hide:target {display:block;}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#like.hide:target,
#comment.hide:target,
#share.hide:target,
#save.hide:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='like' class='hide'>like</div>
<div id='comment' class='hide'>comment</div>
<div id='share' class='hide'>share</div>
<div id='save' class='hide'>save</div>

<a href="#like">like</a>
<a href="#comment">comment</a>
<a href="#share">share</a>
<a href="#save">save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript approach would be as follow:

`like.style.display = "none";`

You could implement if statement to trigger that line if this is what you prefer.